# "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract"

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, soap-client

Yes, I know the question is probably a repeat, but bear with me here. I've tried what I've seen in ALL other questions of the same type and STILL haven't managed to get this working.

I'm working with .Net 4.0 in VS2012 Ultimate. I have a class library that's supposed to reference a web service. Going through the usual steps (Add Service Reference > enter service URI > Go > find the available service > give it a name > OK) creates the service reference and adds a `system.serviceModel` tag in the `app.config` file of my class library.

This class library is currently being referenced by a WinForms app that's passing data to it, to be validated with the returned data from web service. However, upon creation of the service client object...

```
SHWS.StaticXMLAPISoapClient wsc =
    new SHWS.StaticXMLAPISoapClient();
```

...the code crashes with the error noted in the question title, "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'SHWS.StaticXMLAPISoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."

I have tried EVERYTHING I've found on the net, from copying the `[class library name].dll.config` file to the output folder of the WinForms app, to copying the `system.serviceModel` tag from one config file to the other, and still no luck.

I'm literally at my wit's end. Any help would be VERY appreciated, since this is one of the key points of the app I'm working on at the moment. Apologies for my ridiculous request, and thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried **adding** the **same system.serviceModel** sections/settings to your **WinForms app.config** file ?

Comment: Yep, tried that and then the exception complains that there's two endpoints. "An endpoint configuration section for contract 'SHWS.StaticXMLAPISoap' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name."

Believe me, like I said, I've tried EVERYTHING I've found on the net, including what you suggest and *moving* the `system.serviceModel` settings to the WinForms `app.config` file, all with no luck.

Comment: Ok ..so remove the [class library name].dll.config

Comment: Would upvote you if I could, but my rep isn't enough. You pointed me in the right direction after more than six hours of mindlessly aiming around trying to solve the issue. Thanks very, VERY much.

Comment: @fbordas Is good to know that but can you mark this as the answer ?

Comment: This also solved my problem. I had a very similar scenario (WinForms app calling a library which references a service) and by copying the system.serviceModel section of the referencing library to the WinForms app, I was able to resolve the same errors as the OP. Not exactly intuitive...

Comment: Thanks @MauricioGracia this solved my issue too, I had the service reference set in my data layer but need to moved the service model section into my web.config of my web application.

Comment: @AntButcher is very importan to COPY the section and not move it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

...You know, this is why I sometimes hate this world of software development. I removed the class library config file, moved the `serviceModel` settings to the WinForms app, and ***specified the name of the endpoint binding I wanted***, and by some stupid miracle, it decided to start working now.

```
SHWS.StaticXMLAPISoapClient wsc =
    new SHWS.StaticXMLAPISoapClient("StaticXMLAPISoap");
```

Using that instantiation call instead of the one posted in the question, in addition to adding the `system.serviceModel` settings to the WinForms `app.config` file seems to have solved the issue and now I can communicate fine with the webservice.

Oh well. Such is the magical world of programmming.

I still don't know WHY it works like this, so if anyone feels like enlightening me, I'll very much appreciate it.